# Wordpress MySQL data retrieval Hotel booking reservation system

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to create a Hotel reservation system using wordpress. Now, I know all the queries for data retrieval in a non-wordpress mode but I am facing some data-organization issues in dealing with wordpress. My hotels details are stored in the posts table and as custom fields for the hotel. For rates of the hotels, I created a different table according where rates vary according to months. I'd like the data to be displayed like this in my search results page:

```
Hotel_1 Name: (Will come from Post Name)
Hotel_1 Details: (Will come from custom fields)
Hotel_1 description: (will come from excerpt)
Room_1 Name for Hotel_1: Total Rates for selected dates 
Room_2 Name for Hotel_1: Total Rates for selected dates 
----------------------------------------------------------
Hotel_2 Name: (Will come from Post Name)
Hotel_2 Details: (Will come from custom fields)
Hotel_2 description: (will come from excerpt)
Room_1 Name for Hotel_2: Total Rates for selected dates 
Room_2 Name for Hotel_2: Total Rates for selected dates 
----------------------------------------------------------
and so on and so forth.....
----------------------------------------------------------
Pagination>> 

----------------------------------------------------------
```

My rates table looks like this

```
mysql> select * from rates;
+-------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------------+------------
+-----------+--------------+-----------+------------------------------------+
| primary_key | post_id | room_id | room_type            | start_date | end_date
| adultRate | extraBedRate | childRate | inclusions                         |
+-------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------------+------------
+-----------+--------------+-----------+------------------------------------+

where post_id = ID of the post in wp_posts table
room_id = ID given to a room
room_type = Name of the room
```

1 post (post_id) may have several room_types.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

I just need help on 
a. how to organize or create relationships among table to get desired result, &
b. how to get them displayed in wordpress. Some classes or functions need to be considered.

I am very very new to php and mysql and this is my first assignment. My skill level is such that I can make changes to a code but right now it is very difficult for me to write from scratch. However with the help around here I intend to learn.

thanks

Comment: I suggest you start with a PHP and mysql tutorial of which tons are easily searchable on google.

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching this problem from the wrong point of view. There's a better way to handle this kind of information on WordPress and it doesn't (necessarily) involve creating new tables. WordPress handles CRUD natively so you will use pre-made functions instead of writing it from scratch.

Also, forget about using the original posts structure to do this, it can be a major headache. Instead, read everything you can about [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and specially this [awesome tutorial from Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress)

Comment: Thank you moraleida and hakre. I am reading the tutorials and I am also reading custom post types regularly. I am sure I have the wrong approach but what can be expected from someone who doesnt know much. However, I believe I shall be able to do it soon. I was just looking for some help/direction here. Time is valuable. Once I do find the solution, I will post here for others. But until then, I just wish someone opens a window for me here. Thanks.